# Understanding 'impossible'

Tags: dependent-type, idris

[Type-Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) presents:

```
twoPlusTwoNotFive : 2 + 2 = 5 -> Void
twoPlusTwoNotFive Refl impossible
```

Is the above a function or value? If it's the former, then why is there no variable arguments, e.g.

```
add1 : Int -> Int 
add1 x = x + 1
```

In particular, I'm confused at the lack of `=` in `twoPlusTwoNotFive`.

Comment: Idris wiki has explanation of `impossible`: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/wiki/Unofficial-FAQ#where-is-agdas--pattern-and-what-is-impossible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`impossible` calls out combinations of arguments which are, well, impossible. Idris absolves you of the responsibility to provide a right-hand side when a case is impossible.

In this instance, we're writing a function of type `(2 + 2 = 5) -> Void`. `Void` is a type with no values, so if we succeed in implementing such a function we should expect that all of its cases will turn out to be impossible. Now, `=` has only one constructor (`Refl : x = x`), and it can't be used here because it requires `=`'s arguments to be definitionally equal - they have to be *the same `x`*. So, naturally, it's `impossible`. There's no way anyone could successfully call this function at runtime, and we're saved from having to prove something that isn't true, which would have been quite a big ask.

Here's another example: you can't index into an empty vector. Scrutinising the `Vect` and finding it to be `[]` tells us that `n ~ Z`; since `Fin n` is the type of natural numbers less than `n` there's no value a caller could use to fill in the second argument.

```
at : Vect n a -> Fin n -> a
at [] FZ impossible
at [] (FS i) impossible
at (x::xs) FZ = x
at (x::xs) (FS i) = at xs i
```

Much of the time you're allowed to omit impossible cases altogether.

I slightly prefer Agda's notation for the same concept, which uses the symbol `()` to explicitly pinpoint which bit of the input expression is impossible.

```
twoPlusTwoNotFive : (2 + 2 ≡ 5) -> ⊥
twoPlusTwoNotFive ()  -- again, no RHS

at : forall {n}{A : Set} -> Vec A n -> Fin n -> A
at [] ()
at (x ∷ xs) zero = x
at (x ∷ xs) (suc i) = at xs i
```

I like it because sometimes you only learn that a case is impossible after doing some further pattern matching on the arguments; when the impossible thing is buried several layers down it's nice to have a visual aid to help you spot where it was.